# 油断させる, who is being careless/unprepared?

Tags: grammar

In 暗殺教室 chapter 3, the students try to assassinate the teacher and fail and the teacher remarks:

> 笑顔が少々わざとらしい
>   油断させるには足りませんね

But im a bit confused about whether 油断 here refers to the students carelessness about hiding their true intentions ("such carelessness will not be enoughj (to catch me)") or if it refers to the teacher's own carelessness/unpreparedness.

I think since that the subject seems to be the students that 油断させる would then refer to the teacher's own unpreparedness, but i'm not 100%

Comment: "Their smiles seem a little forced. That won't suffice to [make me let my guard down | cause me to be careless]."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the listeners here are the students, the following can be said.

> 「[笑顔]{えがお}が[少々]{しょうしょう}わざとらしい。」
>
> 「[油断]{ゆだん}させるには[足]{た}りませんね。」

First, whose 笑顔 is being talked about?  The students', agreed?  If yes, the phrase "your smiles" might make an appearance in the next sentence.  This being Japanese, however, its "appearance" might as well be ***invisible***.

The next sentence 「油断させるには足りませんね。」 is a complete one though it lacks both a subject and object.  You might want to fill in the missing parts either on paper or in your head.  (Nothing is missing to the Japanese-speaking mind, needless to say.)

> 「(Subject) + **は** + (Object) + **を** + 油断させるには足りませんね。」

「油断させる」 is causative, so the Object is the one who may or may not 「油断**する**」, right?

Thus, it is saying that the Subject is 足りない ("not good enough") to ***make*** the Object 油断する ("to be off guard").

Subject: 「(Your) わざとらしい笑顔 or 笑顔のわざとらしさ」

Object: 「わたし」

A good translation has already been given in the comment section above.  If the listeners are indeed the students, change the "their" in that TL to "your".

Comment: Sorry, but while your explanation seems correct, the translation suggested in the comment you refer to is inconsistent with your words. You say the subject is "you" ("you are not good enough" = if someone was good enough she would make me go off guard), senshin suggests it is an objective statement "just causing me going off guard is not enough" = I can be caught off guard, but still I will survive (because of some extra protection for example). The key is には here.

Comment: @macraf I think you misread senshin's translation.  If he wrote "**It** won't suffice to" what you say would make sense, but he wrote "**That** won't suffice to".